# java program in new terminal ubuntu

Tags: java

how can i start a java program in a new terminal window ?

when i say

java myprog

it starts on the same terminal window. I want it to go onto a new terminal window. in ubuntu

Comment: Terminal windows are OS specific and have nothing to do with Java.  What OS are you using, and what shell?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention that its for ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use `xterm` as your terminal program

```
xterm -e java myprog
```

should do the trick. Or

```
gnome-terminal -e "java myprog"
```

with  `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: isnt there a universal command that would work on all linux terminals ?

Comment: @user602774 The `-e` flag works with `xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `rxvt` and `Konsole`. Maybe a de facto standard?

Comment: I think xterm is fairly universal, since most (if not all) Linux desktops use X11-based desktops and xterm comes with x11

Comment: That's true, also Mac and [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/) versions are X11-based. Maybe `xterm` could be in an optional package and some installations don't have it? I know it's in Mac X11 and Ubuntu, but I'm thinking in Arch Linux or Gentoo, for example.

Answer (score 1):

On windows:

```
cmd /c "java myprog"
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Yep I just noticed the comment too, sorry flagger.

Answer (score 0):

The command to open a new terminal window depends on what desktop you use (gnome, KDE, XFCE...). For gnome (Ubuntu) the command is `gnome-terminal`, for KDE (Kubuntu) `konsole` (I think...). `xterm` should work also on most distributions.